# Java Main Class to load GUI not running

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Hi I have a main class named main.java and in it I have:

```
import my.rcsv1.accounting.DBConnect;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
        RCSAccV1GUI gui = new RCSAccV1GUI();
    }

}
```

I have two other classes DBConnect and RCSAccV1GUI. The DBConnect class contains the following:

```
public class DBConnect {

    public Connection con;
    public Statement st;
    public PreparedStatement pst = null;
    public ResultSet rs;


    public DBConnect(){
        try{
            String driverMySQL = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
            Class.forName(driverMySQL);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=pass");
            st = con.createStatement();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);          
        }
    }
}
```

RCSAccV1GUI Class is a blank JFrame which just has one label currently which is a title.

```
package my.rcsv1.accounting;

import my.rcsv1.accounting.DBConnect;

public class RCSAccV1GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public RCSAccV1GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RCSAccV1GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
}
```

When I run the main class in NetBeans it keeps running and does not produce the JFrame. Why will it not open the JFrame when I run the main class?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Can you also show your RCSAccV1GUI class?

Comment: Does `RCSAccV1GUI` set itself to visible?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the relevant code of the RCSAccV1GUI class. As you can see it is set to visible.

Comment: Are you sure JFrame is not visible? As you have nothing added to it, it will much small, may be you didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
    gui.setVisible(true);
```

after

```
    RCSAccV1GUI gui = new RCSAccV1GUI();
```

or inside this block

```
public RCSAccV1GUI() {
    initComponents();
}
```

set the visibility as true.

Answer (score 1):

Java starts just the `main` method in the class you run, not in other classes. Move the code from your frame class into a constructor or, better, a separate method that you call from `main`.

Comment: Okay I understand that. But even when I just run the RCSAccV1GUI class nothing shows up and it says its running. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Not sure, but running a debugger and watching the threads is where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `setVisible(true)` when the JFrame is created? JFrames are not visible by default.

Edit: As well as adding `gui.setVisible(true)` in the "main" class, remove the main method from "RCSAccV1GUI". I don't think you want to have two main methods, and you also have another instance of RCSAccV1GUI being created there.